# Closed formula for Stirling Cycle Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

The unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind (or Stirling cycle numbers) ${k\brack n}$ count the number of permutations of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, \cdots, k\}$ with exactly $n$ disjoint cycles.

It is well known that $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{{k\brack n}\frac{z^k}{k!}}=(-1)^n\frac{(\ln(1-z))^n}{n!}.$$

Is there a known generalized closed-form expression for the related function

$$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{{k+1\brack k-n+1}z^{k-n}},$$ where $n=1, 2, 3, \cdots$? If yes, can anyone refer me to some literature on that?

Comment: By computing the first few values, it appears that they are rational with denominator $(1 - z)^{2n + 1}$ and numerator polynomials given by https://oeis.org/A008517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with the following claim

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
Q_r(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} {n+r+1\brack n+1} z^n =
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2r+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
z^k.}$$

We will prove this by induction. Introduce $P_r(z) = z^r Q_r(z).$ Note
that  depending on  whether ball  $n+r+2$ joins  an existing  cycle or
turns into a fixed point we have

$${n+r+2\brack n+2} =
(n+r+1) {n+r+1\brack n+2} + {n+r+1\brack n+1}.$$

Multiply by $z^{n+r}$ and sum over $n\ge 0$ to get

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+r+2\brack n+2} z^{n+r} =
\sum_{n\ge 0} (n+r+1) {n+r+1\brack n+2} z^{n+r} + P_r(z).$$

The first term is

$$\frac{1}{z} (P_r(z)-r! z^r)$$

and the second one

$$\left(z\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+2+(r-1)\brack n+2} z^{n+1+r-1} \right)'
\\ = (-(r-1)! z^r + z P_{r-1}(z))'
= -r! z^{r-1} + P_{r-1}(z) + z P'_{r-1}(z).$$

This gives the recurrence

$$P_r(z) - r!z^r =
-r! z^r + z P_{r-1}(z) + z^2 P'_{r-1}(z)+ z P_r(z).$$

We obtain

$$P_r(z) = \frac{z}{1-z} (P_{r-1}(z) + z P'_{r-1}(z))
= \frac{z}{1-z} (z P_{r-1}(z))'.$$

We now prove by induction that

$$P_r(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^{2r+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
z^{r+k}.$$

It certainly holds for $r=0$ where the infinite series gives $1/(1-z)$
and it also holds at $r=1$ as well where the sum gives

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} {n+1\choose 2} z^n
= z \sum_{n\ge 0} {n+2\choose 2} z^n
= \frac{z}{(1-z)^3}$$

and the Eulerian numbers produce

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^3} \left[
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle 1 \atop 1
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle z
+ \left\langle\!\! \left\langle 1 \atop 0
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle z^2 \right]
= \frac{z}{(1-z)^3}.$$

Now supposing it holds with $r\ge 1$ we must show that it holds for
$r+1$. Doing the differentiation and multiplication we obtain

$$\frac{z}{1-z} \frac{2r+1}{(1-z)^{2r+2}}
\sum_{k=0}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
z^{r+1+k}
\\ + \frac{z}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{2r+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
(r+1+k) z^{r+k}.$$

Factoring out $1/(1-z)^{2r+3}$ for the moment this becomes

$$z (2r+1) \sum_{k=0}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
z^{r+1+k}
+ (z-z^2)
\sum_{k=0}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
(r+1+k) z^{r+k}.$$

or

$$(2r+1) \sum_{k=-1}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
z^{r+2+k}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{r+1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
(r+1+k) z^{r+1+k}
\\ - \sum_{k=-1}^r
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
(r+1+k) z^{r+2+k}.$$

Here we have included three zero terms, one in every sum. Continuing,

$$(2r+1) \sum_{k=0}^{r+1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r+1-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
z^{r+1+k}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{r+1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
(r+1+k) z^{r+1+k}
\\ - \sum_{k=0}^{r+1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r+1-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
(r+k) z^{r+1+k}.$$

We obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^{r+1} 
\left[(r+1-k) 
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r+1-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
+ (r+1+k) \left\langle\!\! \left\langle r \atop r-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle \right]
z^{r+1+k}.$$

The  Eulerian  number recurrence  (second  order)  according to  [OEIS
A349556](https://oeis.org/A340556) is

$$\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
=
k \left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
+ (2n-k) \left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k-1
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle$$

Putting $n:=r+1$ and $k:=r+1-k$ and restoring the factor in front now
yields

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2r+3}} \sum_{k=0}^{r+1} 
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle r+1 \atop r+1-k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
z^{r+1+k}$$

thus concluding the induction.

**Addendum.** The reader might well wonder how the conjecture from the
beginning was obtained i.e. how we  find the closed form for small $r$
for lookup  in the  OEIS, which  then points  us to  Eulerian numbers,
enabling the whole computation.

Recall e.g. from *Concrete Mathematics* chapter 6.2. that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n\brack m} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}
[w^{n-m}] \left(\frac{w\exp(w)}{\exp(w)-1}\right)^n.}$$

We get for our series

$$Q_r(z) = [w^r] \sum_{n\ge 0} z^n \frac{(n+r)!}{n!}
\left(\frac{w}{1-\exp(-w)}\right)^{n+r+1}
\\ = r! [w^r] 
\left(\frac{w}{1-\exp(-w)}\right)^{r+1}
\sum_{n\ge 0} z^n {n+r\choose r}
\left(\frac{w}{1-\exp(-w)}\right)^{n}
\\ = r! [w^r] 
\left(\frac{w}{1-\exp(-w)}\right)^{r+1}
\frac{1}{(1-zw/(1-\exp(-w)))^{r+1}}
\\ = r! [w^r] \frac{w^{r+1}}{(1-\exp(-w)-zw)^{r+1}}.$$

Note that the fraction is a formal power series in $w$ with no pole at
zero. Continuing,

$$r! \; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{(1-\exp(-w)-zw)^{r+1}}.$$

A CAS like Maple for example can  recognize the pole of order $r+1$ at
zero  which  has now  appeared  and  quickly  compute the  residue  by
differentiation.  This will produce e.g.

$$Q_5(z) = {\frac {{z}^{4}+52\,{z}^{3}+328\,{z}^{2}
+444\,z+120}{ \left( 1-z \right) ^{11}}}$$

which is enough to spot the pattern.

There is  a  closely  related identity  which  has the  Eulerian
numbers      in      increasing      order      at      this      [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121168/).

Comment: Is there a formal reference for the claim you wrote at the beginning of your submission? Do you know of a textbook, article, etc., where I can find it?

Comment: I derived this one myself though it seems sufficiently simple to have appeared elsewhere already, a long time ago presumably.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please let me know if you find it somewhere. I have been searching for it to no avail.